# Was Rip Hunter referring to Superman and Batman in an episode of Legends of Tomorrow?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

I don't watch Legends of Tomorrow, but I saw an old trailer of an episode where Rip Hunter was saying

> I've seen darker days, I've seen men of steel die and dark knights fall

Was he referring to Superman and Batman here ?

Does it mean that he's been in a timeline where they both existed and died ?

Comment: Well, Superman does exist in a side universe.

Comment: @Adamant he doesn't in the main univerese of Arrowverse, right? And Rip didn't travel across the Multiverse.

Answer (score 2):

Since Legends of tomorrow is part of DC universe and he is a time traveler AND since legends already met Kara Zor-el, its safe to assume that meeting Kara's brother, superman and his frenemy Batman at some point in time is a possibility. Anything is possible when multiverse exists. Even though Rip was not present during the invasion episode, he has a whole timeline as a time master which we don't know about where this could have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Superman does not exist on Earth-1, I think the writers were just putting in a fun Easter egg.